# Is there any indication of a follow up to 17776?

Tags: 17776

[17776](https://www.sbnation.com/a/17776-football) (or "What football looks like in the future") has had a short and successful run.

Update: it is ongoing but scheduled to end 15 Jul 2017.

> the short story “17776” will play out in daily installments of experimental fiction until July 15. The story should excite sports nerds and literary folk alike.
>    - [src](https://qz.com/1024077/an-explanation-of-sb-nations-what-football-will-look-like-in-the-future-17776-by-jon-bois/)

Given its [popularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/17776#Reception) has the author ([Jon Bois](https://twitter.com/jon_bois)) made any statement about wanting to continue? Or conversely has it been confirmed as a one off?

Comment: Just watching it now. Fun

Comment: I think this one is too early to have a qualified answer. The initial project isn't finished yet, so until the initial project is completed there is no telling when or even if the author plans to do a follow up.

Comment: @onewho it is very near completion. Of course, the author may not have decided yet but they could have stated something either way as well.

Answer (score 1):

A very quick look on the creator's account on twitter would strongly suggest that 17776 remains an *ongoing* project and that he's enjoying making them.

The latest <s>chapter</s> <s>segment</s> <s>episode</s> piece went online just a few days ago.

> [@Jon_Bois](https://twitter.com/jon_bois/status/885192306495827974) - uh oh. new 17776 -
>   https://www.sbnation.com/a/17776-football/no-no-no-no-no-no-video …

Comment: The writer does state it will end on 7/15/2017.

Comment: The last episode is meant to be today. I should make that clearer in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably.

The author did a [Q&A about 17776](https://www.sbnation.com/2017/7/24/16003968/17776-questions-and-answers)

> q: Will you expand upon the story in the future, or is this it?
>
> a: I’d really like to! I already have some ideas.